# How do I iterate over ViewChildren's children

Tags: angular

I am using ngFor to dynamically create containers. I want to iterate over the children divs for each of these containers. I am able to console.log a container's children array. However, when I try to iterate over the children array, it doesn't seem to work.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let i of count">
    <div #containers>
        <div>
            <span>{{'1st div'}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>{{'2nd div'}}</span>
        </mat-chip>
        <div>
            <span>{{'3rd div'}}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>{{'4th div'}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

```
  @ViewChildren('containers') containers: QueryList<any>;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.containers.changes.subscribe((containers) => {
      const firstContainer = containers.toArray()[0];
      const childrenArr = firstContainer.nativeElement.children;
      console.log(childrenArr); // works      

      childrenArr.forEach((child) => {
        console.log(child); // never logs anything
      });      
    });
  }
```

EDIT: Seems like I can access the children by index, so using a for loop works. The `childrenArr` is a `HTMLCollection` and not an array, which makes sense why we can't use `forEach` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, `childrenArr` is `HTMLCollection` and not an array, thats why you cannot use forEach.

To loop through `HTMLCollection` (which is a DOM Collection iterable), you can use `for(.. of ..)` as described in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

> The `for...of` statement executes a loop that operates on a sequence of
> values sourced from an iterable object. Iterable objects include
> instances of built-ins such as `Array`, `String`, `TypedArray`, `Map`, `Set`,
> `NodeList` (and other DOM collections)...

Therefore you can iterate through the child elements like this:

```js
for (let child of childrenArr) {
  console.log(child);
}
```

Keep in mind that `HTMLCollection` is automatically updated when the underlying document is changed. Therefore it is a good idea to make a copy (e.g., using Array.from) to iterate over if you plan on adding, moving, or removing child nodes. In that case, you can use your original `forEach` iteration code since we will be converting `HTMLCollection` to `Array` (which is read-only).

```js
Array.from(childrenArr).forEach((child) => {
  console.log(child);
});
```